# Solving error just by changing anything irrelevant in package code

Tags: python, spyder, autofill

I have a strange problem with the python package "fillpdf".
After starting spyder and running the code:

```
fields=fillpdfs.get_form_fields(source_pdf)

field1=1
field2=2

fillpdfs.write_fillable_pdf(source_pdf, filled_pdf, fields)
```

I get an error for one specific PDF:

```
AttributeError: 'PdfArray' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'
```

The codeline that causes the error is the definition of "raw":

```
   def to_unicode(self):
        """ Decode a PDF string to a unicode string.  This is a
            convenience function for user code, in that (as of
            pdfrw 0.3) it is never actually used inside pdfrw.

            There are two Unicode storage methods used -- either
            UTF16_BE, or something called PDFDocEncoding, which
            is defined in the PDF spec.  The determination of
            which decoding method to use is done by examining the
            first two bytes for the byte order marker.
        """
        

        
        raw = self.to_bytes()


        if raw[:2] == self.bytes_bom:
            return raw[2:].decode('utf-16-be')
        else:
            return raw.decode('pdfdocencoding')
```

But if I just remove an empty line above the definition of "raw" or ANY other irrelevant change and save the change, the error in my programm does not occure anymore, even though i did not change anything operative in the code.
Then I can run the programm and my pdf is filled automatically.

After restarting spyder, the same problem: Error until i cange somethinge compleetly irrelevant in the package code, and no problems after that.

How can this be possible?

Comment: Please add your system, python version, project layout (including venv folder location) and invocation command to your question. It looks like this problem is not with library code, but with your setup or something else.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.